# How to install Cordova plugins in Netbeans IDE? 8.0

Tags: java, javascript, html, cordova, netbeans

I'm just getting into javascript development so please bear with me.

I'm trying to install the SpeechRecognizer plugin into Cordova/a Cordova project (which is built into Netbeans IDE 8.0 )
and I really don't know where I have to begin. Could somebody help me out with this? How do  install the plugin, how do I call the function? How do I get a string or array returned to me conntaining what the speech recognition picked up?

Thanks so much, I'm a total noob.

The plugin is SpeechRecognizer - https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer

Answer (score 1):

You can do following:

- open [projectFolder]/nbproject/plugins.properties file
- paste following at the end of file

`SpeechRecognizer=https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer.git`

- build project

The plugins.properties file contains list of used plugins. Some "core" plugins can be added/removed easily in project properties but for 3rd party/unknown plugins, you need to manually modify the file (it is also mentioned in project properties dialog ->Cordova->Plugins)

**Edit:** The pasted line could look like

`com.phonegap.plugins.speech=https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer.git`

or

`com.phonegap.plugins.speech.SpeechRecognizer=https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer.git`

in case of some issues (I was able to build the project with the 1st line with friendly name but in case there is some catch, try this name instead)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, will I then be able to call the speechRecognizer() function in the html and/or javascript without having to add any scripts to the head/html/js/whatever? I mean, how do I now call this function in my page after having done what you said above

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything else. Have a look at https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer/blob/master/README.md there is a sample snippet code with usage. The HTML only contains script element with Cordova.js which I think is created during build.